# Vue bootstrap image overflow scroll in carousel

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a vue bootstrap carousel, it displays images with 100% width. With portrait images I'd like vertical scrolling to be possible, so I can see the bottom of the image. I can't get it to work - I get a scrollbar, but it is "greyed" out, inactive, doesn't work.

```
<template>
<div class="gallery" >
  <b-carousel controls :interval="0">
    <b-carousel-slide 
      v-for="image in images" 
      v-bind:key="image.href" 
      :img-src="image.href" 
      :text="image.text" >
    </b-carousel-slide>
  </b-carousel>
</div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.gallery {
  z-index: 1052;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y : scroll;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `min-height: 100%;` to `height: 100%;` fixed this.

I also changed `overflow-y : scroll;` to `overflow-y : auto;` so I only get scroll bars on the portrait images.